# Execute some calls to one API twice per day at 12.00 AM and 23:00 PM with Java and vertx

Tags: java, vert.x

I've been playing a bit with `vertx.setTimer` and `vertx.setPeriodic` but I didn't find a simple way in java to get execute one scheduled task(call to one API in concrete period ,for instance at 12.00 AM and 23.00 PM).
I've looked as well a blog about vertx and chime ( https://vertx.io/blog/time-scheduling-with-chime/)  but I am not sure it's got support or consistency for vertx version 3.9.0.
Any idea ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/quick-start.html should be fairly easy to integrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try java.util.Timer, example run everyday at 21:00:

```
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            vertx.runOnContext(event -> { System.out.println("timer in vert.x context!"); });
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    timer.schedule(timerTask, today.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));
```